# Infragistics Ultragrid cell C# Datetime is coming 2000

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

I have an object
 [image]

as we can see it is year 1800, but when i bind this on ultragrid, i am getting 01/01/2000 in my dropdown cell.
It should be 1800?

Comment: It seems that there was a bug in some Infragistics previous versions. Consulting this [link](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/24885.aspx) may help you.

Comment: @Bioukh hey, i have found one more thing in my drop down cell "min year" i can toggle is 1930. Is this the issue? and how to set min value for the same.